# Getting TypeError in Card Class

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, class

*This is the Output Below. I get my standard deck of 52 cards but it is followed by a TypeError I don't understand where I'm getting the error message from or how to fix it ive tried numerous things but it either doesn't print anything or it'll give me a TypeError again with non-string (type Card)*

```
decks = Deck()
print(decks)
2 S
3 S
4 S
5 S
6 S
7 S
8 S
9 S
T S
J S
Q S
K S
A S
2 C
3 C
4 C
5 C
6 C
7 C
8 C
9 C
T C
J C
Q C
K C
A C
2 D
3 D
4 D
5 D
6 D
7 D
8 D
9 D
T D
J D
Q D
K D
A D
2 H
3 H
4 H
5 H
6 H
7 H
8 H
9 H
T H
J H
Q H
K H
A H
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Python Shell, prompt 3, line 1
builtins.TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)
```

**I want it to be able to display my deck of 52 cards in a matrix but if i cant even get it to display normally it's frustrating.**

```
import random
class Card:
    def __init__(self, rank, suit): # initialize number variables here
        self._rank = rank
        self._suit = suit
        
    
    def __str__(self): #overload this to get a readable string representation of our card object
        return str(self._rank) + ' ' + str(self._suit)
    
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if self._rank == other._rank:
            return True
    
    def __ne__(self, other):
        if self._rank != other._rank:
            return True

class Deck:
    def __init__(self): 
        # create a list of card objects only need to pass in self
        #intialize a string or list of suits
        #intialize a string or list of ranks
        # building the list of cards
        
        self._deck = []
        self._dealt = []
        suits = ['S', 'C', 'D', 'H']
        ranks = ['2', '3' , '4', '5', '6', '7' , '8', '9','T', 'J' , 'Q', 'K', 'A']
        for suit in suits:
            for rank in ranks:
                self._deck.append(Card(rank,suit))
        
        
    def __str__(self):
    
        for i in self._deck:
            print(i)
```

**desired output:**

```
2 C, 3 C, 4 C, 5 C, 6 C,
7 C, 8 C, 9 C, T C, J C,
Q C, K C, A C, 2 D, 3 D,
4 D, 5 D, 6 D, 7 D, 8 D,
9 D, T D, J D, Q D, K D,
A D, 2 H, 3 H, 4 H, 5 H,
6 H, 7 H, 8 H, 9 H, T H,
J H, Q H, K H, A H, 2 S,
3 S, 4 S, 5 S, 6 S, 7 S,
8 S, 9 S, T S, J S, Q S,
K S, A S
```

Thankyou for any help in advance it is truly appreciated!

Comment: What format is the desired matrix in? Currently what you are doing is creating and printing a 1D list.

Comment: the format is {}, {}, {}, {}, {},\n{}, {}, {}, {}, {},\n... @LucasNg

Comment: im trying to display the list using Card class

Answer (score 0):

`__str__` is not supposed to print anything. It's supposed to RETURN the string to be printed. That's your problem.

```
class Deck:
    ...
    def __str__(self):
        return '\n'.join( str(i) for i in self._deck )
```

Comment: Thankyou Tim it worked in displaying my numbers horizontally i will try to find a method to print in the format i need!

Answer (score 0):

When you print(deck), it uses deck.**str**.  First since inside **str** you print each card, they print, then **str** doesn't return any value, so you get the error message.

Change deck.**str**:

```
def __str__(self):
    
        return self._deck
```

Comment: I made a mistake typing the answer, I put deck._self when I meant deck._deck.  I edited my answer.

Comment: It's still not right.  You need "self._deck".

Answer (score 0):

To fix the TypeError, you need a return value from `__str__`. It's ok (but not recommended) to print stuff though, just make sure you return a string.

To print it in your desired matrix form, you could create a numpy array and print that:

```
import numpy as np

class Deck:
    def __init__(self): 
        # create a list of card objects only need to pass in self
        #intialize a string or list of suits
        #intialize a string or list of ranks
        # building the list of cards
        
        self._deck = []
        self._dealt = []
        suits = ['S', 'C', 'D', 'H']
        ranks = ['2', '3' , '4', '5', '6', '7' , '8', '9','T', 'J' , 'Q', 'K', 'A']
        for suit in suits:
            for rank in ranks:
                self._deck.append(str(Card(rank,suit)))
        
        
    def __str__(self):
        return str(np.array(self._deck).reshape(13,4))

deck = Deck()
print(str(deck))

>>>
[['2 S' '3 S' '4 S' '5 S']
 ['6 S' '7 S' '8 S' '9 S']
 ['T S' 'J S' 'Q S' 'K S']
 ['A S' '2 C' '3 C' '4 C']
 ['5 C' '6 C' '7 C' '8 C']
 ['9 C' 'T C' 'J C' 'Q C']
 ['K C' 'A C' '2 D' '3 D']
 ['4 D' '5 D' '6 D' '7 D']
 ['8 D' '9 D' 'T D' 'J D']
 ['Q D' 'K D' 'A D' '2 H']
 ['3 H' '4 H' '5 H' '6 H']
 ['7 H' '8 H' '9 H' 'T H']
 ['J H' 'Q H' 'K H' 'A H']]
```